# Trying to create an If Statement with a number of conditions

Tags: excel-formula

Formula conditions are

- Cell D5 to equal M
- Cell F5 to be 0 or greater than 0
- Cell H5 to be 0 or greater than 0 and is a percentage

First condition is that `D5 equals M`.

If false the result is `0`

Second condition is that Cell `F5 is greater than zero`.

If both are true the result is F5.

If first is `true`, second is `false`, and third is `true`, the result is the calculation.

I have used the following code which calculates correctly but when cell D5 is not M, I get the calculation value

```
  I8 = IF(AND(D5="M",F5>0),F5,(B8/1.1)*H5)
```

I have tried the following code also

```
 I8 = =IF(AND(D5="M",F5>0),IF(AND(D5="M",F5=0),((B8/1.1)*H5)))
```

but the result is "`FALSE`"

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm going around in circles

Comment: `= IF(AND(D5="M",F5>0),F5,(B8/1.1)*H5) ` seems to be working for me. If B8=1.1, F5=9, H5=1.5, when D5="" then I8=1.5, when D5="M", I=9. If I switch F5 to "" then I8=1.5, regardless of D5.

Answer (score 0):

See if this does what you want:
`=IF(D5<>"M",0,IF(F5>0,F5,H5*(B8/1.1)))`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the text with your calculation.

You have an uncoverd case. First true, second false and third false. If you need something more please leave a comment.

```
I8=IF(D5="M",IF(F5>0,F5,IF(H5>=0,"YourCalculation","First true, second and third false")),0)
```